# How can use vuetify expansion panel @click?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

If I use `<a>`, `<v-btn>` expansion panel design is always broken, How can use `click` event in this situation?

I tried to use `filters`, `watch` and `computed` but I didn't.

This is my code :

```
 <v-card xs12 sm6 md12>
         <template v-for="item in activityitems">
              <v-layout v-bind:key="item.ActivityID">
                     <a @click="activityList(item.ActivityID)">
                        <v-expansion-panel>
                           <v-expansion-panel-content>
                               <template v-slot:header>
                                    <v-card flat>
                                       <v-card-title>
                                        <span class="grey--text">
                                              Name:{{item.ActivityName}}
                                        </span>
                                       </v-card-title>
                                     </v-card>
                                     <v-card flat>
                                        <v-card-title>
                                          <span class="grey--text">
                                              Date:{{item.ActivityDate}}
                                          </span>
                                         </v-card-title>
                                      </v-card>
                                  </template>
                             </v-expansion-panel-content>
                         </v-expansion-panel>
                       </a>
                 </v-layout>
          </template>
</v-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

you Can pass `@click` directly to the `<v-expansion-panel>` tag

like this pen

https://codepen.io/gonjeshk/pen/MWWPveX?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-expansion-panels>
      <v-expansion-panel
        v-for="(item,i) in activityitems"
        :key="i"
        @click="activityList(item.ActivityID)"
      >
        <v-expansion-panel-header>{{item.ActivityID}}</v-expansion-panel-header>
        <v-expansion-panel-content>{{item.ActivityName}}</v-expansion-panel-content>
      </v-expansion-panel>
    </v-expansion-panels>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    activityitems: [
      { ActivityID: "Learn JavaScript", ActivityName: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.' },
      { ActivityID: "Learn Vue", ActivityName: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.' },
      { ActivityID: "Play around in JSFiddle", ActivityName: 'sed do eiusmod tempor aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.' },
      { ActivityID: "Build something awesome", ActivityName: 'sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.' }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    activityList: function(id){
        console.log(id)
    }
  },
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),

})
```

Comment: I think this solution true but I am using vuetify v1.5 so its not working. but Thank you for helping me :)